# How to get reference to store in react/redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-universal

In my reactjs-universal component I wrote this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return {
    cars: store
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchForm)
```

In the same component I would like to dispatch an action like :

```
 store.dispatch({type: 'SHOWDETAIL', data: 'hi'});
```

When this is run I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _create2.default.dispatch is not a function
```

Is it possible to get a reference to the store somehow in my component so I can dispatch the action?

Comment: Check out the simple ToDo app from the docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: I don't think it is that simple but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connect` will call `mapStateToProps` with the state as argument not the store.

It seems that in your case you don't need reference to the store, and using connect to map dispatch to the props is enough.

```
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
  return {
    cars: store
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    action : () => dispatch({
      type : 'ACTION_NAME'
    })
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchForm)
```

If you really want the store you should just export it from where you create it and import it where you need it, it isn't the purpose of `connect` to pass the store.

Comment: How do I actually dispatch the action then, I tried this.props.action() but does not do anything?

Comment: that's weird this.props.action() should have worked, can you give a link to a codepen which reproduce the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a reference to the store object, but to the state inside of the store. The second parameter of the connect function is mapDispatchToProps. This gives you access to the dispatch function.